How open are advisors to accepting PhD students with research proposals relevant to, but outside, their specific focus?
Say somewhere out there, a prospective PhD student is applying for the following fall semester admission and has identified several potential advisors, and emails them to discuss how they'd be a good fit for the advisors' labs and research goals. The student's research proposal bridges two relevant fields yet distinct fields, say, control theory and hypersonic flight; but, this intersection isn’t currently a focus in their labs, which lean more toward vehicle/material design. How inclined would the professors be to consider taking on this student in their labs?

Is this just about how they will like if you send this as research proposal, or are you really determined to do it, and looking for a supervisor for exactly this project? In some places they want you to send a research proposal, but what happens when you actually start there is a different story.

Very very few applicants know enough about the field to know what a good research proposal would actually be.

The answer might be different for an applicant that comes with funding and an applicant expecting to be funded by a grant that the professor has but is tied to some project with its own reserach line.

I'm not exactly determined to specifically pursue what I'm proposing as I understand that an advisor knows what is the best direction for a student to conduct research in. To be honest, I did not consider before that funding is a much bigger factor for any advisor, so I have to be absolutely convinced that the lab I hope to research in very closely lines up with what I hope to do.

In my field (neuroscience; biomedical science) PhD students are normally paid from their advisor's grants and incur research expenses that are paid from their advisor's grants. There is some freedom to pursue future directions under the general umbrella of a previous grant, but otherwise it doesn't really matter what the professor wants exactly. If they don't have a grant for the project a student wants to do, then they can't really take them on.
Your field may differ, but I'll caution you that a frequent genre of question on this site is something along the lines of "my advisor doesn't understand/isn't an expert in my topic. I'm now in my 4th year of my PhD and haven't made any progress and there isn't anyone around who can help me". In many of these cases, the student is blaming their advisor for these circumstances and I can't help but be quite puzzled about where that conclusion came from.

Let me add to the answer of Bryan Krause for fields like math and CS. This answer has a US perspective.
The difference is that funding normally comes from the department in the form of a TA or (more rarely) an RA. It is usually, not always, independent of grants to the supervisor. Thus, there are fewer formal blocks.
But even then, advisors are, and should be, reluctant to take on a student who proposes something outside their specialty. It will make it difficult to advice that student; difficult to suggest resources, difficult to suggest approaches, difficult to evaluate the work.
That doesn't mean impossible. Occasionally a student will come along who can actually produce doctoral level results without any help at all. The problem here is that those students are hard to recognize, especially with the required accuracy. If the wrong choice is made a student could wind up like the horror stories that Bryan mentions.
In summary, it is a dangerous situation with a too-high likelihood of failure. I'd guess that fewer than one out of a hundred doctoral students could manage it. I don't think that any of my peers (in a very large math department) could have done so. The advisors advice is just too valuable, but they have to be knowledgeable about the specific sub-field to give good advice.
One of the problems is that in theoretical fields, insight into what is going on can be very narrowly focused. As an example, a topologist would probably not be a good advisor for someone working in analysis. And that would be especially true in more modern sub-fields.
Not impossible, but beware.

True, although my own graduate work (in mathematics) was a counterexample. My advisor, Andy Gleason,  preferred it when his students found their own problems - whidch I did. Of course he was himself such a generalist that I got lots of necessary good guidance.

From the talk about Hypersonics and Controls, I'll assume you're a prospective student in Aerospace Engineering.  I'm a former professor in Aerospace (albeit at a non Ph.D. granting institution).
In Engineering in the USA, if you aren't funded to get a Ph.D., you don't belong there.
Your professor's job is to apply for grants and contracts in order to fund students.  In turn, students then work within the grants and contracts to earn their keep.  If they're smart, they align their dissertation research with that work so they can graduate efficiently.
There are fellowships (NSF and DOD mainly) that a student can apply for to 'self fund'.  A self-funded student will be welcomed by most professors and will be given more latitude to choose their own research direction.
Some schools will admit MS students without specific funding from an advisor and/or without a specific advisor assigned.  These students will typically be funded by a Teaching appointment and will be expected to transition to a fellowship or Research appointment after their first year or two.
Sometimes you can work to separate your dissertation topic from the contract work you do, but you are certainly setting yourself up for more work -- this freedom is more often granted to senior grad students.
All that said, Hypersonics is a hot area these days.  Most good research universities will have at least someone working in Hypersonics.  Someone working in a broad field (like Design or Controls) may well be willing to look for Hypersonics work even if they haven't done it in the past.  The same is true for someone working in CFD or Optimization or Aeroelasticity -- these kinds of folks are more likely to be Mach number agnostic than someone who works on scramjets or fundamental fluids, etc.
All the interesting work in Hypersonics these days is closely guarded.  Assuming you are a US person, I would suggest you look for an advisor who works in Hypersonics and has a close relationship (established funding record) with the DOD working on Hypersonics.
If you are a non-US person, I suggest you do not work in Hypersonics.  It is a fascinating area, but you'll never escape the challenges of working on a militarized technology as  non-US person.  There are many other interesting problems to work on that won't be anywhere near as sensitive.

Assuming the professor knows enough about the topic to supervise a PhD student on it (see Bryan Krause's and Buffy's answers), then my understanding is as long as there is funding, they're likely to be interested. They might even view it as a positive (since it broadens their research programs).
The caveat of course is as long as there is funding. Funding of this kind can come from:

The student finds it somehow (scholarship from home country or employer or rich philanthropist, self-funding, etc.).
There's a research grant with a component for hiring PhD students.
The student wins a scholarship from the university (example).

Given that the topic is not currently a focus of their lab, #2 is not probable. That leaves #1 and #3, both of which depend strongly on the applicant. #1 requires the applicant to secure funding themselves; #3 requires them to win what is likely to be a highly competitive studentship. Neither of this is going to be easy (although admittedly graduate admissions itself is not easy).

Scholarships are the normal means of funding PhD students in Australia, but most advisors would still be reluctant to take on a student who wasn’t working on a topic directly related to their existing research because they also need to be able to justify the time they put into the project themself: much easier to do if the student is working on something relevant to their own grants.

@Significance I don't read the OP's question as a topic [not] directly related to their existing research though. It seems more like it's a topic that is related to their previous research, but isn't a current focus. In that case, I imagine a free student is highly desirable (assuming one has capacity for another student).

A good advisor will only take you on if they are convinced they can supervise you well enough so that you will succeed in your PhD.  A failed PhD student is not only bad for the PhD student, but also looks bad upon the advisor.  Now, how confident exactly an advisor is to get out of their core focus and still be a reliable source of supervision, strongly depends on the individual and is not generally answerable.
However, some advisors may take you on and then be not great at supervision (see other answers).  So you should not only make sure they are willing to take you on, but also convince yourself that they will be able to supervise you well on a topic outside their core focus.

I don't know about other parts of the world, but in the US, the prof will, or should, be pretty laser focused on advancing their own research.  The far more typical path for a student is to break off a chunk of the advisor's portfolio, and get their experience there, as opposed to having a research plan and shopping for an advisor to host it.
I suppose if the research areas align closely enough, a prof can be nudged in the students' direction, but not without limit.
The one place I tend to encounter rising seniors in college with a developed research plan is in the GRFP process.  Many of the proposals one encounters during that process have sort of a pipe dream aspect that I'm not particularly comfortable with.

You might name a field that your answer pertains to.

I will second your comment on the GRFP aspect. I've encountered it too many times. I find those students know just enough to be "dangerous", and have the self-confidence to see it through, often to their own detriment.

@R1NaNo  it's the strangest thing to me.  A whole panel of reviewers sits there and sort of makes believe that the proposed research will maybe happen, knowing full well that maybe it won't.  I do think that the process tells reviewers a whole bunch about the student, but would really prefer a process that requires less make believe on everybody's part.

@ScottSeidman it is truly not a great process, and I personally do not like judging these proposals. You have to suspend belief that these students will make a worthwhile PhD out of their imagination. This is especially true in lab-based research groups where regardless of the GRFP (which is salary), the student will be bound by the projects and resources of the PIs research focus. The only real value I find from these in learning about the student to see if they write cohesively, and can they make good figures.

@R1NaNo we're about in the same place.  I'm uncomfortable with it that I stopped reviewing them.
